# Rotating enemy characters

Tags: c#, xna, floating-point, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of characters created in XNA C# as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.NumDaleks; i++)
{
    if (dalekList[i].isActive)
    {
        Vector3 line = dalekList[i].direction;
        float rotationDal = (float)(Math.Atan2(dalekList[i].position.Y, dalekList[i].position.X) / (2 * Math.PI));
        Matrix dalekTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(GameConstants.DalekScalar) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationDal) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(dalekList[i].position);
        DrawModel(mdlDalek, dalekTransform, mdDalekTransforms);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get characters to rotate to move in the direction they are facing. I believe this method is where I need to do but cannot figure out how to work out the angle require to go

Comment: First off, why are you dividing by 2pi? XNA uses radians too. Second, you're using the character's position to determine the angle... you should be using the character's velocity if you want to get the angle they are moving in. Third, you seem to have a chicken-and-egg problem: do you want the angle that the character is facing, or the angle that he's moving in? The angle that the character is facing is simply the last orientation you drew the character at.

Comment: Well the 2 Pi was just something I was experimenting with. Ideally trying to get the angle that the character is moving in so that the facing direction can be set to that angle i.e. the character is always facing in the direction its moving